# Image full width and height with no scrollbar

Tags: html, css

In my HTML file I only have an image tag. I set the source attribute by code and want to set this image on full width and full height.

The image itself has this CSS attached

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

and the page itself uses

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {  
  margin: 0;
}
```

Somehow a vertical scrollbar appears. The scrolling range might be around 5px so it's really small.

How can I remove this? I want the `img` being fullscreen with no scrollbar.

Comment: Can you share the HTML?

Answer (score 3):

Please set `display: block` to image as shown in below working snippet then that small margin will be gone.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placekitten.com/1200/1200">
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `margin: 0;` to `html, body`, not only to `body`. And if that's not enough, add `display: block` to the `img`

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 display: block;
}
```

Or if you not able to modify `display` properties then add `vertical-align:top;`:

```
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

add

```
display:block;
overflow:hidden;
```

for an img tag in css than set width and height to 100%
in the end it will be like that

```
img{
   display:block;
   overflow:hidden;
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
 }
```

Comment: overflow:hidden on the img has no meaning